# Wordpress loop > unique loop renders slightly wrong results

Tags: wordpress, loops, if-statement

A few things to understand before my question will make sense:

- I use a hidden category called 'Unique' to specify if the post will use the single.php or a special one used for the unique ones.
- I want the index to act as a single: showing only one post, displaying next/prev post links, and comments also.
- I need the index.php to say if the post is in category 15 (unique) than `<the_unique_content>`, else; `<the_default_content>`

My loop does all this, but the problem is that if the current post is unique, it **also** displays 1 additional post below the unique post.

Here is the loop >

```
<?php $wp_query->is_single = true; ?>

<?php $post_count = 0; ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    

    <?php if ($post_count == 0) : ?>

<?php if (in_category('15')) { ?>   

<?php the_content(); ?> 

<?php } else { ?>   



    <?php the_content(); ?>    



    <?php $post_count++; ?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are setting the query correctly to return a single post. Your code *is* limiting the number of posts through your `$post_count` variable, but in the case where the post is "unique", it only increments to 1 on the second post.

Here is one way to limit the number of posts to a single post. It involves modifying the loop query to set the number of posts per page to one.

```
<?php
global $wp_query;

$new_query = array_merge( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1 ), $wp_query->query );

query_posts( $new_query );

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

etc...